# Objective-C Error : dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/custom_framework.framework/VT_custom_framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, mobile-application

im working on a iOS Project with XCODE Version 7.1.1 with iOS Version : 7.0 as Deployment Target & im using Objective-C Only . I'm Using one of our custom frameworks inside my project .
But the issue is my project is running pretty fine in my simulator and is failing with the Error dyld: Library not loaded: when i'm running same in Device(iOS8) .
when im trying to run the same project with out modifying any content of info.plist in one of my colleague's System,It's working in the other systems pretty fine in Simulator & Device as well . I really dont know whats happening .
I re-installed my XCODE but the issue remained same .
I added my framework in to the Embedded binaries also .
i disabled Bit-code both in my project and in the framework's project also .
 
For your reference I'm posting the complete error below .

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/custom_framework.framework/custom_framework
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/632142A6-4485-41D1-8A65-238112513129/MY_APP.app/MY_APP
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/632142A6-4485-41D1-8A65-238112513129/MY_APP.app/Frameworks/custom_framework.framework/custom_framework: mmap() error 1 at address=0x008C2000, size=0x0000C000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/632142A6-4485-41D1-8A65-238112513129/MY_APP.app/Frameworks/custom_framework.framework/custom_framework
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 doesn't support the loading of dynamic frameworks bundled with the app.  You will need iOS 8.

I am surprised there wasn't an error while building the app in Xcode.

Comment: Hi trojanfoe ,
Thanks for the info but when I'm trying to run the same project in my colleague's system with iOS7 as deployment target its working fine .
the app is getting crashed in my system only,I'm using OS X El-Captain V:10.11.1 .
I really don't know whats happening in my PC

Comment: OK you're going to need to examine the app bundle.  Is the `.dylib` in the bundle?  What's the rpath set to in the executable (use `otool` to find out).